# Не могу понять изменение указателя в hash table structure (C Interfaces and Implementations: Techniques for Creating Reusable Software)

Tags: c

В третьей главе вышеупомянутой книги приводится реализация таблицы атомов. В частности, там приводится реализация функции, отвечающей за довавление новой строки в таблицу

```
static struct atom {
    struct atom *link;
    int len;
    char* str;
} *buckets[2048];



const char* Atom_new(const char* str, int len) {
    unsigned long h;
    int i;
    struct atom *p;

    assert(str);
    assert(len >= 0);

    for (h = 0, i = 0; i < len; i++)
        h = (h<<1) + scatter[(unsigned char)str[i]];

    h %= NELEMS(buckets);
    for (p = buckets[h]; p; p = p->link)
        if (len == p->len) {
            for (i = 0; i < len && p->str[i] == str[i];)
                i++;
            if (i == len)
                return p->str;
        }
    p = (struct atom *)malloc(sizeof (struct atom) + len + 1);
    p->len = len;
    p->str = (char*)(p + 1);
    if (len > 0)
        memcpy(p->str, str, len);
    p->str = '\0';
    p->link = buckets[h];
    buckets[h] = p;
}
```

scatter - это массив `unsigned long scatter[]` содержащий 256 элементов
В оригинале вместо `p = (struct atom *)malloc(sizeof (struct atom) + len + 1);` написано `p = ALLOC(sizeof(*p) + len + 1)` и дано пояснение, что

> The call to ALLOC above allocates the space for both the atom
>   structure and for the sequence, and the sequence is stored in the
>   immediately succeeding bytes.

так что замена, если я правильно понимаю, верна.

Конкретно я не могу понять вот эту строку

```
p->str = (char*)(p + 1);
```

Что означает этот сдвиг на единицу? Разве при таком сдвиге указатель не будет указывать на память за границей структуры? Разве нельзя обойтись без этой строчки, коль скоро у нас выделена память на всю структуру (включая строку) и с помощью memcpy мы просто копируем строку в p->str?

Comment: `p->str = '\0'`??? В коде написана чушь. Либо вы  неправильно перепечатали. Либо этой книге место в топке.

Comment: Да я опечатался, но вопрос был не в этом, тем более что я уже получил на него ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Что означает этот сдвиг на единицу? Разве при таком сдвиге указатель не будет указывать на память за границей структуры?

Да, так и задумано, после сдвига указатель будет указывать за границу структуры, и именно там будет хранится строка, как и описано выше. Заметь, память как раз выделяется под саму структуру, под длину строки и под нулевой байт. И str будет указывать на эту память. Это даёт определённую гибкость, хотя и весьма сомнительную.

т.е на 32-х битной little-endian машине память выделенная под структуры со строками `'qwerty'` и '`asd`' после инициализации может выглядеть примерно так:

```
    +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
    |f0|ff|00|00|00|00|00|06|xx|xx|xx|xx| q| w| e| r| t| y|00| 
    +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
    v           v           v           ^
    |           |           |           | 
 +--link        len         str---------+ 
 |  |                                   |
 |  |         struct atomic             |
 |  |___________________________________|
 | 
 +->+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
    |00|00|00|00|03|00|00|00|fc|ff|00|00| a| s| d|00|
    +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
    v           v           v           ^
    |           |           |           | 
    link        len         str---------+ 
    |                                   |
    |         struct atomic             |
    |___________________________________|
    ^                                   ^
    |                                   |
    p (00 00 ff f0)                     (p+1) (00 00 ff fc)
```

> Разве нельзя обойтись без этой строчки, коль скоро у нас выделена память на всю структуру (включая строку) и с помощью memcpy мы просто копируем строку в p->str?

Можно, если строка всегда хранится вместе с заголовком списка, то обычно делают несколько по-другому (синтаксис С99):

```
struct atom {
    struct atom *link;
    size_t len;
    char str[]; 
};
```

В конце структуры объявляется массив без указания длины, в результате обращения к нему сразу будут трактоваться, как обращения к памяти за основной структурой. В остальном код полностью аналогичен за исключением этой строки `p->str = (char*)(p + 1);`. До C99 обычно объявлялся массив переменной или единичной длины (что с современными компиляторами может приводить к предупреждениям).

ЗЫ: Вероятно дальше ошибка, вместо `p->str = '\0';` должно быть `p->str[len] = '\0';`

Comment: Погодите. Но если память выделена сразу на всю структуру вместе со строкой, то разве это не значит что этот сдвинутый указатель будет указывать и за границу строки тоже? Или "+1" значит что указатель сдвигается на один байт? Но тогда это тоже глупость так как int занимает 4 байта и link занимает 4 байта.

Comment: @Алексей, разрисовал подробно, может так понятно будет... `(p+1)` сдвигает указатель на `sizeof(*p) == sizeof(struct atomic)` байт.

Comment: Понял, спасибо.